# Minecraft server permissions to step on pressure plate

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I own a Minecraft server and I have downloaded world edit and world guard to protect my server from griefers. I like world edit and all, but the players can't activate this pressure plate at the spawn, that I use to teleport them to another location. I don't want to have to edit the *permissions.yml* file, because as I hope you know, I'm terrible with that kind of stuff.

Comment: I don't see what's the question here?

Comment: The question is implied but it's really unclear. You have to edit the permissions file I'm afraid.

Comment: Did you select the and define the region via WorldGuard?

Comment: @Brayjamin Well did you use WorldGuard?

Answer (score -2):

Set the `interact` flag of the spawn region to `allow`!